# How to make an tiled background like on the web?

Tags: iphone

On the iPhone, how could I achieve the same tiled background effect?

For example, I have an pattern image which I want to repeat only horizontally. Would I have to go the route in -drawRect: by myself and loop over to draw the pattern, or is there a convenient method to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext      = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparency.png"];
    CGContextDrawTiledImage(currentContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, 12, 12), [img CGImage]);
}
```

In this example "transparency.png" is a 12x12 image.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the backgroundColor of the UIView with a pattern using the following snippet:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.png"];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

The image will automatically be tiled for you to cover the area.

Claus

Comment: thanks Claus, that works great. But unfortunately transparency in the image turns black with this.

Comment: Is the view the backmost view, or do you have a non-transparent view behind this one?

Comment: I hav no transparent view behind it. It is a subview of the colorful superview with images and background color...

Comment: Odd. Have you verified that the png file actually contains a transparent image. How does it display in e.g. Photoshop and Preview?